# Problems about responsiveness and keyboard/mousepad not working

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, ati

So I installed Ubuntu 12.04, I'm very new at this and want to get into the world of Linux but have run into nothing but problems. I have an Acer Aspire 5553g.

- First off, my keyboard won't work.
- Second, my computer has more than enough of everything to run Ubuntu
  smoothly, but everything runs extremely slow. (You move the mouse and
  it gets there a few seconds later) It's to the point where I can't
  even use it and I really want to.

I'm tired of Microsoft stuff and I've been looking at learning how to use Linux based operating systems for a while. Please send me some help to fix these issues and maybe some tips to help get me started.

Thanks in advance

chris

Comment: Check this - maybe it will help:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1555029

Comment: @ChrisTheNoob: Welcome to Linux.  I guarantee you there is a solution to your problem; and that you'll love Linux once you get it working. After reading Marty's comment--have you checked your BIOS yet? What version is it?

Answer (score 1):

[**This link**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1555029) which was [suggested by Marty Fried](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151069#comment182966_151069) points to an [ubuntuforums.org](http://www.ubuntuforums.org) discussion thread. The solution suggested in that thread is to update the BIOS of the *Acer Aspire 5553G* to v1.17.

This supposedly fixes the keyboard problem. Could this possibly apply to your situation?

The most recent [BIOS available from Acer](http://support.acer.com/product/default.aspx?tab=5&modelId=2232) for the Aspire 5553G now appears to be v1.23 and is dated May 23, 2011. If it was me I would (1) verify that BIOS could be used on my computer and, if it could, (2) download it and (***carefully!***) update my BIOS.